# Subir archivos a un servidor desde app IOS con swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, http, post

Estoy haciendo una app con la que puedes subir imágenes a un servidor(Está en `PHP 5.2`).

Primeramente para subir la imágen lo haci en el momento que se daba click al botón subir desde la app y mostraba un `alertview` con una barra de carga, pero tardaba demasiado.

Actualmente lo he cambiado para que cuando se de al botón de subir desde la app, el `body` de la petición `http`, se guarde en la base de datos y luego cuando se navega a un `view controller` se activa la subida desde el `background` asincronamente, asi el usuario no pierde tiempo.

El problema es que al guardar en la base de datos y luego volverlo a leer, la petición `POST` no funciona correctamente y no me manda el body de la petición

Nose si esta es la mejor forma de hacerlo o hay otras mejores y mas eficientes.

Os dejo un ejemplo de mi código haber si es correcto:

```
//Aqui genero el body de la peticion
func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: String?, filePathKey: String, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String, nameParam: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData()
    let mimetype = "image/jpg"
    let nombreImagen = obtenerNombreImagen()

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(nameParam)\"\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendString("\(cadenaParametros)\r\n")

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey)\"; filename=\"\(nombreImagen)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendData(imageDataKey)
    body.appendString("\r\n")

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    return body
}

func subirImagen() {
    if (myImageView.image != nil) {
        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image!, 1)

        if(imageData == nil) {
            return
        }

        let body: NSData = self.createBodyWithParameters(paramString, filePathKey: "imagen", imageDataKey: imageData!, boundary: boundary, nameParam: "param_img")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
            GestorDB.uploadFiles("Imagen", ruta: stringUrl, parametros: paramString, body: body, tipoPeticion: "POST", respuesta: "", estado: 0)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                progressAlert.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(-1, animated: true)
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message:
                    "Imagen añadida correctamente", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("volver", sender: self)
                }))
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
    }
}

/*Clase gestorDb*/
//El campo de la tabla donde se guarda el body es tipo TEXT
class func uploadFiles(nombre: String, ruta: String, parametros: String, body: NSData, tipoPeticion: String, respuesta: String, estado: Int) -> Bool {
    let ubicacionDB = self.obtenerRutaDB()
    let database = FMDatabase(path: ubicacionDB as String)
    if !database.open() {
        return false
    }
    else {
        let sentenciaSql = "INSERT INTO archivo(nombre_archivo, ruta_archivo, parametros, body, tipo_peticion, respuesta, estado) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        if !database.executeUpdate(sentenciaSql, withArgumentsInArray: [nombre, ruta, parametros, body, tipoPeticion, respuesta, estado]) {
            database.close()
            return false
        }
        else {
            //print("INSERT CORRECT")
            return true
        }
    }
}
//Obtengo los datos
class func getFilesToUpload() -> FMResultSet {
    let ubicacionDB = self.obtenerRutaDB()
    let database = FMDatabase(path: ubicacionDB as String)
    if !database.open() {
        //print("No se puede abrir la bbdd")
    }
    let sentenciaSql = "SELECT * FROM archivo WHERE estado = 0"
    let results:FMResultSet? = database.executeQuery(sentenciaSql, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
    return results!
}

/*ViewController*/
//Aqui obtengo losd atos de peticion guardadas no enviadas y las envio
if AppDelegate().isConnectedToNetwork() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        if GestorDB.getFilesToUpload().next() == true {
            let resultadoSql = GestorDB.getFilesToUpload()
            while resultadoSql.next() == true {
                let idArchivo: Int = Int(resultadoSql.intForColumn("id_archivo")) // .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
                let rutaArchivo  = resultadoSql.stringForColumn("ruta_archivo").stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
                let parametros  = resultadoSql.stringForColumn("parametros").stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
                var body  = resultadoSql.dataForColumn("body")//.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

                if body == nil {
                    body = NSData()
                }

                AppDelegate().uploadFile(body, stringUrl: rutaArchivo, parametros: parametros, idArchivo: idArchivo)
            }
        }
        else {
            //print("NOOO")
        }
    }
}


/*AppDelegate*/
func uploadFile(body: NSData, stringUrl: String, parametros: String, idArchivo: Int) {
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: stringUrl)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    let boundary = self.generateBoundaryString()

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPBody = body

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        print("*** error = \(error)")
        print("**** data = \(data)")
        print("***** request = \(request)")
        print("****** response = \(response)")
        print("******* response data = \(responseString!)")//Me devuelve vacio

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            GestorDB.updateEstadoFiles(idArchivo)//Aqui solo cambio el estado a 1
        })
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Porqué almacenas en la base de datos? Si quieres tener acceso a información de un view con otro puedes usar `struct`, `class` y protocolos.

Answer (score 0):

Mi recomendación es que al presionar el botón ya mandes el pedido y utilices el pod AlamoFire (https://cocoapods.org/?q=Alamofire) para el manejo de llamadas asincrónicas al servidor.

Como ejemplo de un Post te copio el que se encuentra en la descripción del pod:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "foo": [1,2,3],
    "bar": [
        "baz": "qux"
    ]
]
```

> Both calls are equivalent
>   Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
>   Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding(options: []))

Comment: En lo posible hay que evitar usar frameworks de terceros. Alamofire es muy bueno pero nativamente ya tienes `NSURLSession`.